# IIS Application Pools do not start due to WAS not starting

Tags: iis, windows-10

I have been dealing with an issue with the IIS service. Every now and then, it stops working for me and it is always the same issue: IIS service and App Pools won't start due to WAS service not starting. And WAS is failing due to the strange error: `Windows could not start the Windows Process Activation Service service on Local Computer. Error 13: The data is invalid.`

[image: IIS Down]

[image: WAS Down]

There is a lot of noise on the internet regarding this but nothing works for me:

- The second machine with same Windows 10 Ent has IIS working fine
- Line by line comparisons of the config files in the `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config` directory only resulted in exact matching valid XML files
- The folders that are expected to exist like `C:\inetpub\temp\apppools` are all there
- The registry files related to WAS all match with the second machine

The solution that worked for me was to do a complete removal of IIS and WAS and reboot to reinstall again. I did this many times. However, since two days, the issue came back and I'm not able to get it working by reinstalling.

I have been reading up and trying different things on the internet but I have run out of patience to fix this now.

Here is the series of events that happen when I try to start IIS (in ascending order):

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

And here is a warning that happens right after the above:

[image: 4]

I'd also like to add that I saw a series of errors just before this issue started yesterday:

[image: Other errors]

Now, the once with source: `SMSvcHost 4.0.0.0` is a bit interesting as it has this details:

```
A request to start the service failed.
 Error Code: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' registered for extension 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior' could not be loaded. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config line 247)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetEnvironment.UnsafeGetSectionFromConfigurationManager(String sectionPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetAssociatedSection(ContextInformation evalContext, String sectionPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupCommonBehaviors(ContextInformation context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceSection)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.SharingService.StartControlService()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.SharingService.Start()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.TcpPortSharing.OnStart(String[] args)
 Process Name: SMSvcHost
 Process ID: 3348
```

It is pointing to the machine.config but I don't understand why it is complaining. I thought it was looking for SMB service related which I didn't install in Windows component.

I'm stuck with this right now.

Comment: I got the same issue since windows 10 latest update. Have you figured out some solution?

Comment: Nope. I switched to IIS Express.

Comment: I am stuck with the exact same issue since the last Windows updates. I tried restoring previous versions of the applicationHost.config and administration.config files. There is also something strange going on in the c:\inetpub\history folder with backups being deleted as soon as I copy the files to paste elsewhere. I suspect there's an over-active security mechanism in place that's malfunctioning, but in the meantime I can't get IIS working at all. I guess I'll try the uninstall/reinstall approach and hope it doesn't come back.

Comment: No update from my side. Started to use a docker image for IIS but even that failed.